# Displaying 2 images with 2 windows using octave

Tags: octave

I want to display the images with the independent windows.

The below code doesn't satisfy the requirement.

```
green = imread("green.bmp");

blue = imread("blue.bmp");

imshow(green);

pause(10);

imshow(blue);

pause(10);
```

Is it able to do that?

Comment: call `figure()` to make a new figure.

Answer (score 3):

Add `figure` to achieve it.

```
green = imread("green.bmp");

blue = imread("blue.bmp");

imshow(green);

figure();

imshow(blue);

pause(10);
```